# change the value of an array in a function in many times

Tags: c, arrays, function

Can I write a function that contains an array for example with the size of `16`? In each call of the function, I want to modify a part of the array. I want to call the function `4 times` until the whole array is changed. I should store the result of each call and use the new array after the call until all the array is changed.

Comment: Please be more specific when you ask a question on this site. Try to code your idea and provide then the code and/or the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can...!
Just declare an array as `static` so after the completion of the function execution, the array stack frame won't be cleared.
e.g.

```
void modify_array(void)
{
    static int a[16]={/*'initialise here'*/};
    {
    /*'modify array here'*/
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not neccessary. If you declare an array f.e. in the main and pass the array to the function you can modify it as many times as you want as the stack will be cleared, but the array will be overwritten in the main as you pass an 'adress' (passing by reference, not by value) to the function.

Comment: @Alan as asked "a function that contain an array."

Comment: There is a flaw though, because OP wants to use the array *after the call*. So the function should return a pointer to the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I want to use the result of the modified array another time.That I want to modify a part of the array in each call (many call) until all the array is modified.Please help.I have 2 week blocked I cannot solve this problem

Comment: in each call I sould conserve the new tab until in the last call I have the array completely changed. I should have a function like this

Comment: please the array that I want to return the value of each call is a struct array